# What names for standard website user roles?

Tags: user-roles

What are the standard user role names that a majority of sites could all use? Below is a list of the best roles that I could think of (in order of importance), but I am hoping to find at least ten role names for a user system I am working on.

```
admin:        Manage everything
manager:      Manage most aspects of the site
editor:       Scheduling and managing content
author:       Write important content
contributors: Authors with limited rights
moderator:    Moderate user content
member:       Special user access
subscriber:   Paying Average Joe
user:         Average Joe
```

Another thing that I'm interested in, is whether or not these names translate over correctly into other languages.

Comment: I think the types of names you choose would depend on the context. Moodle (Learning Management System) uses roles like Teacher, Student and Course-Creator. A shopping website might use roles like Buyer, Supplier, Manager. I don't think this is a question that can be so easily generalised.

Comment: You are right that there would be no universal answer. However, as I said I'm looking for names that the majority of sites could all use. I think it's safe to say that most sites are content related (blogs, news, online company identities, etc..) and that as such they all can use some standard role names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to the aspect of content production:

```
editors:       Doing some stuff beyond writing: scheduling and managing content
contributors:  Authors with limited rights
```

Comment: Nice, there can be more than just "authors" after all.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, answer already given, but hell, why not?

```
critic:      can rate and review content, but not create original content
ambassador:  site rep for external communications, has access to site email, PR materials
guest:       duh
emeritus:    retired key users who no longer contribute, but whose contributions are honored
```

Comment: donor // :) You know who are they