# When to use a single-group or multi-group permission system?

Tags: permissions

As far as I'm aware there are two main styles of permissions systems out there. I would like to know if the multi-group option is really worth the extra trouble or system load (more queries). It seems that with proper application design there is no need for users to have more than one class - though my applications have never made it big enough for me to know.

- [Simple user system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598411/standard-website-user-role-names) (group/role with users)

Sam is a **member** - he cannot access **admin** content. Joe is an **admin** - he can change **author** posts.
*One user* is in *one group*, and groups cascade permissions. Think wordpress.

- Multi-group user system (users with groups/roles)

Sam is a **member** *and* **moderator** - but he still cannot access admin content. Each user can have *many groups* which all combine to show what he can/cannot do.

Why not just have Sam as a moderator and all moderators inherit member privileges? Also, which one works better with ACLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One application I worked on recently involved several "work areas", each of which a user can be provisioned to access.  These work areas, e.g., A, B, and C, are not hierarchically related, so a user could have access to A and C, but not B, or any other combination.  In a case like this, inheritance doesn't help and a user needs to be assignable to multiple roles.

Comment: Thats a good example. But couldn't the application have been designed to use a cascading approach instead?

Comment: No, because the work areas are totally independent. Being provisioned for one work area does not imply any access to other work areas, though it's possible for users to have access to several. Imagine an application where each project a company works on requires secure access, and some employees work on multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that two groups might inherit permission from one lower group, but those two groups cannot share permissions.

Say, for example, you have users that can post to the forums.

Then, you have people in charge of moderating users. Those people can reset passwords, ban users, promote users, etc. Plus, they can post to the forums.

You have another group in charge of moderating content. They can modify/delete posts, rearrange the posts, etc, but they cannot do anything with user accounts. Plus, they can post to the forums.

Then you have the administrators who can do it all.

In this case, the user moderators and the content moderators both inherit from general users, but do not share permissions. There are certainly cases where multiple-group systems are useful, but they definitely aren't necessary in every system.