# Can I do it with only session or do I need ACL?

Tags: php, mysql, session, acl

I am planning to create a simple project management system with PHP/MySQL/Codeigniter.

There will be a super-admin, an admin and around 20 users. User A, B, C...

And there will be around 50 projects. Project 1, 2, 3 ...

User A and B will be able to access project 1 pages, User C, D and F will be able to access project 2 pages etc.

Can I do it with session?

Or do I need to use ACL?

How should I structure the DB?

Can you give me your ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

As sessions are mere tools to save user-specific data in, you are going to need some sort of access control. Some examples:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193309/common-cms-roles-and-access-levels/1860713#1860713) is how I like to do it using a home-made ACL system.

[Zend_ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) is said to be very good, but I haven't worked with it myself yet.